# In Unity 2d, how can I get an input field to always be wanting input even after enter is pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

im making a console game in unity and for the input field you have to click it after every time you press enter and submit text but I want it to always be wanting input from the user. and even after you press enter its still selected / on and accepting input. if anyone has any ideas that would be really helpful. thank you!

[Using TMP for this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3yMH.png)

I just looked into the editor and didn't really find anything. i also looked on google but its not really common and so I wasn't seeing what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have a function that runs `On End Edit` that processes your input. If you add the following line of code to this function, you will automatically regain focus on your `TMP_InputField` and select whatever text is in there.

```csharp
field.ActivateInputField();
```

If the text is NULL, no selection is made.

If you want to specify the selected range you can use the following commands:

```csharp
field.selectionAnchorPosition = 3;
field.selectionFocusPosition = 10;
```

This will select the text from the 3rd symbol to the 10th. If anchor and focus are the same the cursor will simply jump to the position with no characters selected. If the specified values are out of the range of the string the selection is automatically adjusted to the best of its ability.